# Remove the border around the title bar

Tags: html, css

Ok I this light grey showing threw close to the curves in the title bar "Indie News"  Its actually the background showing, Not a boarder.

[Link to image](http://hostmypicture.com/?v=example.)

I have this as my html , i think that it has a table inside a table is causing this? but not sure.

```
<div id="contentwrapper">
    <!-- NEWS START -->
    <table width="100%"><tr><td>
        <div class="rounded">
            <div class="rounded_top">
                <div>Indie News</div>
            </div>
            <div class="rounded_content">
                <font align='Right'><a href="#" >Submit Your Story</a> </font>           
            </div>
            <div class="rounded_bottom">
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end of rounded-->
        <table><tr><td align='center'>
            <div id='coin-slider'>
                <a href="images/newsimage/minecraft1.jpg" target="_blank">
                    <img src='images/newsimage/minecraft1.jpg' >
                    <span>
                    Minecraft still an indy game?
                    </span>
                </a>
                <a href="images/newsimage/spider1.jpg">
                    <img src='images/newsimage/spider1.jpg' >
                    <span>
                    Spider just released!
                    </span>
                </a>
            </div><!--end of coin slider-->
        </td></tr></table><!--end of coinslider table-->
    </td></tr></table><!--end of news start table-->

    <!-- Reviews start -->
    <!-- Review #1 -->
    <table style="border:none;">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="4" width="30%" bgcolor='#7e7e7e'><IMG SRC="images/review image/dj.jpg" ALT="Dinomight jack"></th>
            <td><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none" >Review of Dynimite Jack </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>By <i>Bob Bobby</i></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Now here's a surprisingly nice piece of news. Stealthy demolition game Dynamite Jack has already been a reasonable .</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor='#7e7e7e'><a href="#" > 0 comments</a> | <a href="#" >Leave a comment</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table><!--end of review table-->

</div><!--end of contenet wrapper-->
```

also the css..

```
    /***************/
/* CONTENT */
/***************/
#contentwrapper{
display: table-cell;
width: 700px;
background: #919191;
border: None;

}

#contentcolumn{
margin: 0 20% 0 20%; /*Margins for content column. Should be "0 RightColumnWidth 0 LeftColumnWidth*/
}

#contentwrapper table {
border: none;
width: 100%;/*around 700 max for images*/
border-collapse: collapse;
}




/***************/
/*content round box*/
/***************/
.rounded {
   background: #000000;
   width: auto;
}
.rounded_top div {
   background:  url(../images/up-left641.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.rounded_top {
   background: url(../images/up-right641.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.rounded_bottom div {
   background: url(../images/down-left641.png) no-repeat bottom left;
}
.rounded_bottom {
   background: url(../images/down-right641.png) no-repeat bottom right;
}

.rounded_top div, .rounded_top, 
.rounded_bottom div, .rounded_bottom {
   width: auto;
   height: 25;
   font-size: 24px;
   font-weight:bold;
   text-align:center;
   color:#ffffff;
padding:-40px;
}
.rounded_content { margin: 0 20 0 20;}
.rounded { color:#000000;}
```

all suggestion are welcome. 
thanks
glen

Comment: the gray border is a result of a margin that's been set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a good idea to reset the styles when creating a website to ensure compatibility between browsers. The style would go something like:

```
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 border:0;
}
```

you can see this in more detail here: http://www.cssreset.com/

Comment: worked great.. i added it under my body tag in the css. or should i make this above it.. or does it not matter  :D

Comment: It makes no difference. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi now **define** `#contentwrapper, .rounded` `border raius`

```
#contentwrapper, .rounded{
border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
-webkit-border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:20px 20px 0 0;
}
```